# Existe alguna configuración de VSCode que me lleve a la función cuando le de clic encima?

Tags: vscode

Recuerdo cuando usaba netbeans si le dabas clic encima de la función, te llevaba a donde la función fue declarada, ¿existe alguna configuración en vscode que haga lo mismo?

Edit: lenguaje Laravel/PHP

Comment: depende del lenguaje hay varias exenciones... pero esta pregunta tiene respuestas basadas en opiniones ya que existen múltiples exenciones...

Comment: @BetaM como el software cuenta con una opción nativa que es invariable y editando la pregunta; no es basado en opiniones.

Comment: @BetaM pregunto por las dos cosas por que desconoce en general que tiene el editor y viene de usar un IDE con ciertas funciones nativas, no un editor de código que depende de plugins. preferí ayudarle con editar la pregunta y que evite las opiniones, que cerrarle la pregunta por desconocimiento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS Code presenta dos paquetes de soporte a lenguaje php y laravel

la primera opción es [Intelisense](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense) que ya vienen por defecto en el VSCode es nativo [no es una opinión].

La segunda opción es usar un plugin que de soporte a php laravel
En el caso de los plugin hay multiples opciones; deberás explorar cual se apega mas a tu uso.